# Lucene - Reading all field names that are stored

Tags: lucene, indexing, web-crawler

I need to populate a dropdown with all field names in a lucene index and need to show those values. I was able to do it successfully using

```
var luceneIndexReader IndexReader.Open("D:\path_to\index_directory", true);
var allAvailableFieldNames = luceneIndexReader.GetFieldNames(IndexReader.FieldOption.ALL);
```

Only problem is I need to include only 'Stored' fields in the drop down. This list includes all 'Indexed' and/or 'Stored' fields in it. Is there a way to query/search the indexes if a field has any 'stored' values and thereby filter out this list?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that every document in the index can have different fields containing stored fields. Since those are not storef as inverted index (they are stored per document) you can't retrieve them from the IndexReader. You need to retrieve one specific document, e.g. `Document doc = indexReader.document(1);` and call `Fieldable fields[] = doc.getFields();`. Then iterate over them and checking: `field.isStored();`.

Comment: I was wondering if I can do a search for 'stored' value using some kind of search expression to find if a field has any stored values. That would help with limiting the drop down only to stored values.

Comment: Can you be little more exact: Do you want to search for documents with a stored value or do you want to search for fields with a stored value?

Comment: I would say 'want to search for fields with a stored value'.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no direct option for that. I think you have the code for writing the index. So it is hard coded or somehow decided on runtime which field gets stored. You need to get the information from that place. When all documents are index the same way, you can retrieve the first document in the index and retrieve the stored documents like I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Late at the party, but in the meanwhile you can just call `FieldInfos# GetEnumerator()`

See https://github.com/Shazwazza/lucenenet/blob/docs-update-jan2020/src/Lucene.Net/Index/FieldInfos.cs/#L168